React children as component that renders another component
I'm using Select component by NextUI (the question is not about Next UI).
The Select component expects children with SelectItem component by NextUI.
This works:
export const Select: FC<SelectProps> = ({
  isInvalid = false,
  variant = "flat",
  children,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <NextSelect variant={variant} isInvalid={isInvalid} {...rest}>
      <SelectItem key={"1"}>Select item</SelectItem>
    </NextSelect>
  );
};

It works because the children includes SelectItem.
However, this won't work:
export const AnotherComponent = () => {
  return <SelectItem key={"1"}>Select item</SelectItem>;
};

export const Select: FC<SelectProps> = ({
  isInvalid = false,
  variant = "flat",
  children,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <NextSelect variant={variant} isInvalid={isInvalid} {...rest}>
      <AnotherComponent/>
    </NextSelect>
  );
};

The error thrown is TypeError: type.getCollectionNode is not a function.
What's the difference between the two approaches that causes the second one to fail?

SelectItem was a child of NextSelect but now it's a grandchild

The other approach doesn't work because you're passing as a child an object of type ReactComponent instead of a SelectItem.
Instead of passing a component, you could call the AnotherComponent as a function :
<NextSelect variant={variant} isInvalid={isInvalid} {...rest}>
      AnotherComponent()
</NextSelect>

but it's cleaner to create a function that could receive params and return a component of type SelectItem rather than a React component, like this :
export function createItem(): SelectItem  {
  return <SelectItem key={"1"}>Select item</SelectItem>;
};


You can define the type of AnotherComponent as FC
or
Call AnotherComponent as function
export const AnotherComponent = () => {
  return <SelectItem key={"1"}>Select item</SelectItem>;
};

export const Select: FC<SelectProps> = ({
  isInvalid = false,
  variant = "flat",
  children,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <NextSelect variant={variant} isInvalid={isInvalid} {...rest}>
      {AnotherComponent()}
    </NextSelect>
  );
};

